# How can I perform arithmetic operations in PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The question is kinda simple (and probably a little silly), but I'll give you an example.
In the project I'm working on, I've created some functions (class methods) that will perform some basic SQL operations for me. All I need to do is to provide info like table name, columns and values as arguments and it will do the rest.

The function structure is basically something like this:

```
public function update_order($order_id, $order_value) {    
    $example_sth = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE example SET example_order = :order_value WHERE example_id = :order_id");
    $example_sth->bindParam(":order_id", $order_id);  
    $example_sth->bindParam(":order_value", $order_value);  
    $example_sth->execute();

    $data = $example_sth->fetch();
    return $data;
}
```

That said, now let's suppose I want to perform a query like this:

```
UPDATE example SET example_order = example_order + 1;
```

Since I use PDO to perform SQL operations, is there anyway I could pass the "example_order + 1" part inside the PDO's bindParam() function, or the only solution is to completely remove the PDO variable and write the arithmetic operation directly in the query?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE**

There's an additional information that, for the sake of simplicity, I didn't include in the question. As there are some confusions being raised, I will including this here for those trying to understand my intentions with all of this.

The project I'm working on is an RPG-like site, with users having attribute points, items having special effects, and so on.
All of this user attributes and item effects are created or manipulated by admins.

Since these item effects varies a lot in what they'll do (it could simply give an user more attribute points, but it could also perform more complex operations, like creating or deleting a whole profile), the only solution I came to was to turn these effects into SQL operations.
In order to avoid a security breach, I, of course, wouldn't allow an admin user creating an item to save for themselves these SQL operations, so what I decided to do was to save simple JSON commands, like:

```
{"update":[
    {"columns":"order_id, order_value",
    "values":"16281738, 16"}
]}
```

The admin user would, through a simple control panel, choose what they want the item effect to do, and the JSON would be auto-generated based upon that.

At the time the effect is being executed by a common user, all of this JSON commands must be passed to the class methods responsible for the SQL operations (the ones I mentioned above).

Now as I have been asked: why do I have to save arithmetic operations?

The answer is:

If one of these item effects was created specially to an user, I know I could simply perform the calculation by myself before creating the item effect, so the JSON command would already include the final result (for example, ""column": "life_ponts", "value", "77"").
But since these operations/item effects are not destined specifically to an user, they must be subjective (that is, work based on the user that is executing them at the moment).
Because of this, the only solution I came to by now was to save not the final result (as this is impossible for this situation), but to save the arithmetic operation that must be done on those attribute points.
So, when I save ""column": "life_points", "value": "life_points + 1"", what I'm trying to do is to get the life_points from the user executing the command at the moment, and increase it by 1.

I know it sounds confusing and maybe even wrong, so I'm totally open to better suggestions.
Sorry for the misunderstandings, I hope you guys can help me out here.
Regards!

Comment: Why would you need to bind it at all? The point of binding params is to prevent SQL injections, i.e. users injecting SQL code in your query. If you just wanna increment a value by one, you can execute the query you have. There's no user input.

Comment: Yes, I know that, @AurelBílý. But the class method I've created should work as a standard for all UPDATE operations related to that table, so it should accept all kinds of information (including user input or simple arithmetic operations like the one mentioned in the question). It varies a lot when I'm going to do one thing or the other, so I didn't want to need to change the method just because of a query that's not fitting.

Comment: How would the arithmetic operations be sent by the user? how would the input look like?
Would then this script update always the same fields, or the fields that are updated depends on the user input?

Comment: In the asked query, is the example_order a value passed by the user? if so, you can increment it via simple arithmatic operation and then insert it, rather than doing it in query.....

Comment: @Dragos, the fields updated are the fields necessary to create that element. I'm using these methods to make it easier to create, update or delete elements like profiles, posts, categories and settings. So, for example: in order to create a category, the fields being affected would (always) be title, description and image. But when updating a setting, the setting value could be the pure information (like order_limit = 16) or an arithmetic operation (order_limit = order_limit + 1). Being the method a standard for all UPDATE operations, it should work in both cases.

Comment: @NewbieJavaDeveloper, yes, the example order receives user input, but the problem is: this user input could be either the pure information (like $order_value = 27) or a simple increase/decrease to the value that's already in the database ($order_value = $order_value [the value already in the db] + 1). That's why I cannot be sure whether the input will be pure information or a simple manipulation to the info already existent, because it accepts both cases.

Comment: @JohnGeorgine the question is: `how does the user input look like in the case of an increment/arithmetic operation?`

Comment: @John Georgine : Your reply to my comment is not clear to me. Can you please elaborate it? I didnt get the point "a simple increase to the value that's already in the database ($order_value = $order_value [the value already in the db] + 1)".

Comment: Hi, @Dragos. I'm really sorry for the confusion that's been created. I updated my question and I hope you can have a better understanding of my situation. Thanks in advance, again!

Comment: Hi, @NewbieJavaDeveloper. I'm really sorry for the confusion that's been created. I updated my question and I hope you can have a better understanding of my situation. Thanks in advance, again!

Comment: It would be a lot easier to solve this using an ORM (see Doctrine, for example).
You would update an object's properties and the ORM will handle the necesary updates in the database.
This way you would not have to reinvent the wheel ;) That work was already done successfully by a whole community

Comment: What @Dragos said - use an existing ORM. There's Doctrine, there's Laravel's Eloquent, there's Propel (no idea if anyone uses Propel though). You're reinventing the wheel, that's simply a waste of your time. You won't create anything better or faster, at best you might create something similar to existing libraries. Be smart, use the code provided to us. It's easy to use, it solves your problem and it lets you focus on what you should focus on - logic of your game.

Comment: @JohnGeorgine : In that case you must first fetch the existing value from the database and then perform the operation and then update it. Doing any arithmetic operation in the query is not a good practise.

Answer (score 0):

Binding is designed for the field **value**, not name. What you are looking for is a white list of fields that can be changed.

If you want to take this further, I suggest doing something like this:

```
{
    "update": [
        {
            "column": "order_id",
            "type": "relative|absolute",
            "value": 16281738
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is what's happening:

1. You set the action per column, instead of a set of them. You **should** use a **whitelist**!
2. A new field is added - "**type**". It can take two values only: **relative** and **absolute** which specify what type of action to preform. If it has any other value then it's a risk and you should discard or throw an exception.
3. The value is an integer/float. When you `json_decode` you should cast this to int/float or check `if (is_numeric())`. This is important because you can safely substitute int/float into sql query without the risk of injections.

Finally you said that sometimes you need complex actions - use the **type** field to specify it. However if you don't need other values, consider using a boolean instead